# Java: Declaring an object values when trying to add to another object

Tags: java

I got way to familiar with only using Python and I can't seem to figure out if there is an easier way to add nested objected.

Example making a nested list in Python is this simple:

```
list = [[1,2,3],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]]
```

Is there a way to do something like this in Java? Or do I have to declare an empty object and then add one by one like

```
Vector<Vector<String>> example = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
String[] thisIsAStringArray = {"AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE"};
Vector<String> example2 = new Vector<String>();
example2.addAll(Arrays.asList(thisIsAStringArray));
example.addElement(example2);
```

Like, there HAS to be a faster way right?

Comment: Java isn't Python; and static typing requires more typing (in the general case). However, in your specific example, `int[][] list = {{1,2,3}, {2,2,2}, {3,3,3}};`

Comment: Collection literals are being implemented in Java 9, so you'll have to wait about 7 more months from now.  However, you can initialize arrays with values `int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, ... };` and lists `List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, ...);`

Comment: There is a useful post to check: [Creating and instantiating arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/99/arrays/404/creating-and-initializing-arrays#t=201607261943570177)

Answer (score 0):

You can declare array in line:

```
int[][] array = {{1,2,3},{2,2,2},{3,3,3}};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following way:

```
Vector<Vector<String>> example = new Vector<Vector<String>>(Collections.singleton(new Vector<String>(Arrays.asList("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE"))));
```

In Java, `objects` need to be constructed or can be assigned with an already constructed objects. (One exception is String objects which can be built from literal, without needing an explicit call to constructor). In Java, Arrays (which are also considered objects) can be initialized from a list of objects or literals. But since you are using `Vector` class, you need to construct the objects by calling constructors.

However if you don't have a hard requirement of using `Vector` or other parameterized collection objects, you can use simple String arrays here:

`String[][] example = new String[][] {{"AAA", "BBB"}, {"CCC", "DDD"}};`